# Subgroups of normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. If every subgroup of $N$ is a normal subgroup of $N$, could we say $N$ is subgroup of centralizer of $N$ in $G$?

Comment: What is $H$? A subgroup of $N$? If you formulate it the way you do now, then $H$ must be abelian ...

Comment: Excuse me dear friends, now the true question is typed

Comment: $N$ is a subgroup of its own centralizer in $G$ if and only if $N$ is abelian. So your question is then, "If the only subgroups of $N$ are normal in $N$, is $N$ abelian?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true: take $N=G=Q_8$, the quaternion group of order 8.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are surely right, but what if N is a proper subgroup of G ?

Comment: Take $G=Q_8 \times A$, with $A$ a non-trivial abelian group and put $N=Q_8 \times \{1\}$.